# Define location of log file during the process

Tags: c#, log4net

I am trying to create the log file without defining his destination beforehand, but during the run time, how to do that? here `MyApp.exe.log4net` :

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <!-- <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}.txt"/>-->
      <file value="D:\Log.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
       <level value="ALL" />
       <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

And here is my log init:

```
// init-log
string appName = Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + ".log4net";
string appPth = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

CLog.LogInit(Path.Combine(appPth, appName));
CLog.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.INFO, "(Program) MyApp application started.");

// init-log
```

And here is `Lib.Clog` class:

```
public static class CLog
{
        public static void LogInit(string configFile, bool useAltLogFileNamePath = false, string altLogFileNamePath = "");
        public static void WriteDebugLog(string header, string subject, string detail, string note = "");
        public static void WriteExceptionLog(string header, Exception ex);
        public static void WriteInfoLog(string header, string subject, string detail, string note = "");
        public static void WriteLog(LogLevelL4N logLevel, string log);
}
```

Now the log file always goes to `D:\Log.log` but I want that the location will be defined at the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this:

```
XmlConfigurator.LogFullFilename = @"c:\path\Myapp.log";
```